# XDocument.Parse Success or Failure?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(somestring);
```

But how do I validate if the string `somestring` is a well formed XML. Is `Try Catch` the only way to do this?

Comment: XML documents are assumed to always be well-formed since they are normally machine-generated.  Exceptions to that rule are reported by, well, exceptions :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is Try Catch the only way to do this?

There is no `TryParse` method for `XDocument`, so `try-catch` is probably the best bet. Also consider validating your XML against a schema since it will not only check if the XML is well-formed, but also checks for constraints.

You may see: [Validation Against XML Schema (XSD) with the XmlValidatingReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/thydszwy(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 7):

If you only need to check whether the document is well-formed, the fastest way is to use XmlReader as follows:

```
var isWellFormedXml = true;
try
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)) // can be a mem stream for string validation
    {
        while (reader.Read()) {}
    }
}
catch
{
    isWellFormedXml = false;
}
```

This way you don't spend memory for XDocument DOM. BTW, XDocument.Parse() uses XmlReader for processing XML, so the exceptions are the same, if you need to analyse them.